# Is it possible to send an email in vb.net without SmtpServer.Credentials = New _ and Net.NetworkCredential

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, smtp

I was wondering if it is possible to send email in vb.net without the following code

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
Net.NetworkCredential("admin@example.com", "password")
```

i am switching servers and i have a lot of websites that send emails with all the same credentials being sent from the server that is getting changed.
My issue is when the change happens its going to affect the sites. My question is what does smptServer.Credentials = New _ really mean? and
Net.NetworkCredentials("admin@example.com, "password") can you send without this. I am fairly new to this and i was looking at classic asp sites that we have and it doesnt require either of these credentials and works. Therefore i was wondering if it is possible to send emails without these in vb.net??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `_` is a line continuation character. Your code is equivalent to `SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("admin@example.com", "password")` on one line.

Comment: classic ASP , don't you mean ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 1):

Some SMTP servers require a client to authenticate itself as a means of protection against relaying spam. Other servers don't. If the server you're using requires authentication, you have to provide it. Otherwise, you don't.